# How to write a query which selects ItemID divisible by 25?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Can you query items whose IDs are divisible by a specific number? For example:

My table contains a list of people marriage in 2016. Each person is given an ID in the column titled "ItemID". The first person on the list has an ID of 1001. I need to display only every 25th person on the list.
Is there a way to write a query that will display only IDs that are divisible by 25?

I have tried a query like:

```
SELECT ItemID
FROM 2016
WHERE ItemID % 25 = 0
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT ItemID, Link
FROM 2016
WHERE IF(MOD(ItemID, 25))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`MOD`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd) operator:

```
SELECT ItemID FROM 2016 WHERE ItemID MOD 25 = 0
```